# An electrified comb can attract bits of paper but not a sheet of paper. Why?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

An electrified comb can attract bits of paper but not a sheet of paper. Why?
Does this indicate that electrostatic force is related to mass like Electrostatic force=ma?

Comment: There are two forces at work: the gravitational force that pushes the bits of paper or sheets of paper down, and the electrostatic field that pulls them up.  Do you expect the gravitational force to be more for the bits of paper or the sheet of paper?

Comment: Your point makes sense. Thank you! And what about relating electrostatic force with m*a?

Comment: In Newtonian mechanics $F = ma$ for any force.  So if $F_e$ is the electrostatic force and $a_e$ is the acceleration due to the electrostatic force, $F_e=ma_e$.  And if $F_g$ is the gravitational force and $a_g$ is the acceleration due to gravity, $F_g=ma_g$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Here in Fe=mae, m is mass of what?

Comment: $m$ is the mass of the object that is experiencing the force (bit of paper or sheet of paper).